# Missing xcode dylib dynamic library file

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to compile a project built using an older version of Xcode, the new Xcode (version 8.3.3) says the dynamic library file :

libiconv.dylib

is missing.

When I look into the library directory :

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk/usr/lib

I can find libiconv.2.4.0.tbd but cannot find libiconv.dylib

My question is : 
Do I need to download libiconv.dylib or should I find a way to use libiconv.2.4.0.tbd instead?

Update :

Have added libiconv.2.4.0.tbd as suggested, but the same error persists. Please give some hints.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]**yes libiconv.dylib will not be there in new xocde you need delete libiconv.dylib from xcode and add libiconv.2.4.0.tbd then it will compile**

Comment: Thanks ... I just deleted libiconv.dylib from the left column of the Xcode window. But I can't find a way to add libiconv.2.4.0.tbd to the list. Please give some hints.

Comment: go general settings and go linked framework and libraries section and click on + button then search with libiconv.2.4.0.tbd

Comment: libiconv.2.4.0.tbd seems to have been added, but the error "No such file or directory: 'libiconv' persists. Please give more hints ...

Comment: @Stanley can you please check libiconv is added to your Xcode project or not